# How to add data to Firebase.database() with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I trying to add data to my firesebase but i got some errors, before I was using angular and it works :

```
this.autht.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
    this.profile.email = auth.email;
    this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`)
        .set(this.profile); 
});

this.nav.setRoot('page-my-account');
```

Comment: i think you have a typo in this.auth you wrote this.autht? also please write the error that see in the console.

Comment: This is the example in angular, Im trying to use firebase.auth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
                  this.profile.email = auth.email;
                  firebase.database().object(`profile/${auth.uid}`)
                 .set(this.profile); 
                });